display mode from settings->display disappeared
Display modes are not available under settings->displays.
I refer to Join Displays, Mirror, and Single Display.
Yesterday all was fine. Now there's no option to setup the monitors correctly. I can barely read the current test and make this post.
I appreciate any help you can give me.
I would add a screenshot but I'm not allowed.
Image link: https://imgur.com/a/3JsXLGX
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ uname -a
Linux holdsworth 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsmod | grep nv
nvidia_uvm           1429504  0
nvidia_drm             77824  8
nvidia_modeset       1212416  11 nvidia_drm
nvidia              35643392  508 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
video                  73728  2 asus_wmi,nvidia_modeset
nvme                   61440  5
nvme_core             208896  6 nvme
nvme_auth              28672  1 nvme_core


 gnome-control-center -v
19:04:45.0901                      GLib:    DEBUG: setenv()/putenv() are not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
19:04:45.0907         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Finished creating D-Bus proxy for CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Color,org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties)
19:04:45.0907         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Adding object GDBusProxy (CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Color,org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties) → 0x752a2800fd90) to the storage
19:04:45.0907         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Finished creating D-Bus proxy for CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Color,org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color)
19:04:45.0907         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Adding object GDBusProxy (CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color,/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Color,org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color) → 0x56a46d7f8ea0) to the storage
19:04:45.0907          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to 11:-0
19:04:45.0907          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: setting adjustment -1.000 to 11:-0
19:04:45.0907         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Finished creating D-Bus proxy for CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.Shell,/org/gnome/Shell,org.gnome.Shell)
19:04:45.0907         cc-object-storage:    DEBUG: Adding object GDBusProxy (CcObjectStorage::dbus-proxy(org.gnome.Shell,/org/gnome/Shell,org.gnome.Shell) → 0x752a20009480) to the storage
19:04:45.0907      diagnostics-cc-panel:    DEBUG: ABRT vanished
19:04:45.0915          display-cc-panel:    DEBUG: Resetting current config!
(gnome-control-center:20095): dconf-DEBUG: 19:04:45.916: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
(gnome-control-center:20095): dconf-DEBUG: 19:04:45.916: watch_established: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (establishing: 1)
(gnome-control-center:20095): dconf-DEBUG: 19:04:45.917: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
(gnome-control-center:20095): dconf-DEBUG: 19:04:45.917: unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (active: 2, establishing: 0)
(gnome-control-center:20095): dconf-DEBUG: 19:04:45.936: watch_fast: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (establishing: 0, active: 1)
(gnome-control-center:20095): dconf-DEBUG: 19:04:45.936: unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/mutter/" (active: 2, establishing: 0)

